# C# (500) Internal Server Error overrides original exception

Tags: c#, api, http, httpexception

I am creating an API on C#.
When I have an exception I try to send back a helping message, but 
"The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."  overrides the original one.

The code on server side is this one

```
 string authHeader = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter;

        if (authHeader.Equals(ATOKEN) || authHeader.Equals(BTOKEN))
        {
            //goal reached. Token Authentication is valid.  
        }
        else
        {
            throw new HttpException("Invalid User!");                                  
        }
```

When I try to handle the exception on client side a cannot find the message "Invalid User"!

Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather use [`HttpResponseException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling) like below

```
    var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
    {
        ReasonPhrase = "Invalid User!"
    };
    throw new HttpResponseException(resp);
```

Comment: Ok, but how can I handle the answer? It is located on exception.Response.StatusDescription

Comment: string message = ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusDescription;

Comment: Post code as where exactly you are throwing exceptions